Nested cursors with arcy.da.SearchRelatedRecords
I am trying to use python (arcpy) to filter through some data in my Ancestry-GIS.
All inside the same geodatabase I have:
A point feature class called
places
shape | placename | GlobalID |
Two non-spatial tables:
event
personid | event | date
person
personid | name
places and event are related through a realationship class called event, event and person are related through a relationship class called person
This script does what I want separately. The first search does a search on my kids great-great parents, and the second search gets only the birth records.
import arcpy
import os

places_relc = r'C:\test.gdb\event'
person_relc = r'C:\test\person'


for record in arcpy.da.SearchRelatedRecords(person_relc, origin_fields=["event"], destination_fields=["personid", "name", "ahnentafel"]):
         ahn_value = record[1][2]
         if 16 <= ahn_value <= 31:
             print(record)

for record2 in sorted(arcpy.da.SearchRelatedRecords(places_relc, origin_fields=["placename"], destination_fields=["personid", "event", "date"])):
    if record2[1][1] == 'Birth':
         print(record2)
         
     

What I want is a nested search that gives me a cursor with the people that are within my ahnentafel-range, and then only the their place of birth (that will eventually go into a empty point feature class)
Is it possible to nest the cursors for arcpy.da.SearchRelatedRecords?
